# Apache beam write PCollection<string,pojo> to GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, avro, apache-beam-io, apache-beam-internals

I am trying to put a PCollection<KV<String,POJO>> , I need to write this Pojo to GCS bucket in the avro format, where the string(key) for the map is the GCS folder path that I need to write into . How do I achieve this for streaming fashiom

I tried using AvroIO library but I am struggling to get the gcs folder path dynamically for every element of PCollection.

```
PCollection<KV<String, Pojo>> output; // this has the required data
output.apply(AvroIO.write(pojo.class).to(GCS Path)
               .withSchema(SCHEMA).withSuffix(".avro"));
```

How do I retrieve the GCS path dynamically for every Pojo.

Comment: Have you checked "Writing data to multiple destinations
" in https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/avro/io/AvroIO.html?